# How to create List and libraries using existing Schema Xml with JSOM in sharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, schema, custom-schema

I am developing **SharePoint Hosted app** and I want to create lists. I have lists **schema XML** files. I want to use that schema and create list using JavaScript.
I have tried the following code

```
function createListXML() {
var listName="ParentLT"
debugger;
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('WorkFlowXAML')/items?$select*&$filter= Title eq 'ParentLT'",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        //fetched custom schema
        listxml = data.d.results[0].XAMLSchema;
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
        var webContext = context.get_web();
        var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
        listCreationInfo.set_title(listName);
        listCreationInfo.set_customSchemaXml(listxml)
        var newList = webContext.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
        context.load(newList);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert(oList.get_title() + ' created successfully.');
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    });

}
```

but failed to create list, I got this error:

> Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Is it possible to create list using schema XML in JavaScript?
Suggest some help?

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

to

```
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
```

Comment: it sovle above error but gave another error: Invalid list template